# print number to screen assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to print a number in a register to the screen. Furthermore I want to save it as a string of characters (bytes). So if I had a number like 150, I would want to save it at a certain address as

'1', '5', '0'

```
mov ebx, dword ptr[ebp+8]
; eax contains value
; ebx contains address to store characters

; here is where conversion would take place
```

Since it's in a register, would you have to convert it to decimal value and then separate each place?

Comment: Under what operating system, and what libraries are you allowing yourself?

Comment: x86 Windows. I am aware of multiple libraries being available, but I did this as part of a larger bare-bones program trying to learn more about assembly programming.

Comment: Do you actually mean Windows (like, with graphical windows), or the 16-bit MS-DOS subsystem (like, a DOS prompt)? They're completely different from each other.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Windows as in the full graphical operating system. Like I said, I am aware of numerous ways to solve this problem using system libraries, but that wouldn't really teach me anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´am not sure how to print the ASCII's and how to separate each place. And so i only like to show how to convert the value of EAX to decimal ASCII's and store it to the address of DS:EBX. For a 32 bit value of maximum 0FFFFFFFFh we need a place for ten decimal ASCII's (4294967295). And for example if the value is decimal 150, then we get the ASCII's of "0000000150" with some "0" at the beginning.

```
      mov     cl, 0Ah             ; counter for ten decimal ASCII's
      mov     edi, 1000000000
P1:   xor     edx, edx
      div     edi
      add     al, 30h             ; convert to ASCII
      mov     esi, edx            ; save remainder
      mov     [ebx], al           ; store ASCII to the address of DS:EBX
      inc     ebx
      mov     eax, edi
      mov     edi, 0Ah
      xor     edx, edx
      div     edi
      mov     edi, eax
      mov     eax, esi
      dec     cl
      jnz P1
```

Comment: It seems alright. However, if I didn't want the leading zeroes, I believe you could just add something after the division that would check if the remainder is equal to the original number. `cmp edx, esi`